# Google MD5 cracker (in java)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, hash

i find below code for Cracking Md5 hashes : (from : `aboulton.blogspot.com.tr`)

```
 package md5crack;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Adam Boulton - Using Google to crack MD5
 */
public class MD5Cracker {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        if(args[0] == null || args[0].isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("-= Google MD5 Cracker =-");
            System.out.println("-= Adam Boulton - 2010 =- ");
            System.out.println("Usage: MD5crack <hash>");
        }

        String hash = args[0];
        String url = String.format("https://www.google.com/search?q=%s", hash);

        try {
            URL oracle = new URL(url);
            URLConnection conn = oracle.openConnection();

            //keep Google happy, otherwise connection refused.
            conn.setRequestProperty("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 Windows NT6.1 WOW64 AppleWebKit/535.7 KHTML, like Gecko Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7");

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                    conn.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] words = inputLine.split("\\s+");

                for (String word : words) {
                    String wordHash = DigestUtils.md5Hex(word);
                    if (wordHash.equals(hash)) {

                        System.out.println("[*] Found: " + word);
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println("[!] No results.");
            in.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MD5Cracker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

but in this line i have an error :

```
String wordHash = DigestUtils.md5Hex(word);
```

Error :
    `DigestUtils cannot be resolved`

How can i fix that ?

**and this is good method or Class for crack and finding Decoded MD5 hash ?**

How we can use this with Optimizing on android ?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably need `import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;`

Comment: `import org.apache` can not resolved.error in eclipse .

Comment: Did you download and add to your project commons package from apache?

Comment: @Pshemo : doesnt work.still problem exist...i added `commons-codec-1.7-bin.zip ` and v10 but still not solved...

Comment: Strange. I am using `commons-codec-1.9.jar` and don't have any problem. Did you add this your jar to project classpath?

Comment: yes of course look at this picture : http://i.stack.imgur.com/LYvsP.png

Comment: I always liked adding `jar`s instead of `zip` files. Could you try downloading and including `jar` containing compiled classes?

Comment: i added with `zip` file into this project.what is in your mind ? `.bin` ? please give me a download link : )

Comment: If you downloaded `bin.zip` then it should contain all `jar`s you need. Just extract it somewhere and add `commons-codec-1.x.jar` (where `x` is for instance `10`) to your project.

Comment: one question ? why vote down ? i banned from ask question !

Comment: You shouldn't get banned for one down-vote. Do you have more (even now deleted) posts which ware down-voted/closed? Anyway I would assume that `-1` in this question was caused by fact that error message was quite clear about what is the problem (`DigestUtils cannot be resolved` - lack of `DigestUtils` class in your imports/project) and first thing you ware expected to try was googling for instance `DigestUtils.md5Hex` which would point you to https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html which gives you hint where you can download it.

Comment: Other possible reason for down-vote is that your question is about ruining something which is security mechanism (unfortunately md5 is still used by some companies as only hashing mechanism) and some people don't like when others ask how to break tools they use.

Answer (score 1):

Your program doesn´t know what [DigestUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html) is standing for.

You need to either import it, or download [codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) from the appache common jar and reference it as external jar into your project and import it afterwards

Answer (score 1):

> ... and this is good method or Class for crack and finding Decoded MD5 hash?

Is it going to be effective?  In general, probably not.

There are 340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,211,456 possible different MD5 hashes.  If you have an MD5 hash for an arbitrary string or document, then the chances of finding that hash in Google search results is vanishingly small.

Indeed, it is pretty obvious that Google's search engines wouldn't be able to index more than a miniscule fraction of the possible MD5 hashes.  According to [this article](http://www.sciencefocus.com/qa/how-many-terabytes-data-are-internet), the "big 4" internet companies were estimated to have ~1,200 Petabytes of storage in 2013.  That's a factor of ~10<sup>20</sup> too small just to store all possible MD5 hashes.

However, if you can identify a use-case where mappings between relevant strings and MD5 hashes are systematically published in web pages, then this approach might work ... for those strings.  One such use-case would be MD5 hashes for email addresses, if someone has published the mappings in pages that Google indexes.

Comment: so, what is your idea about Md5 cracking or decoding in best way and fast way ?tnx